# Grails dependencies with slf4j

Tags: java, grails, dependencies, slf4j

`BuildConfig.groovy` dependecies

```
   dependencies {

        runtime('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25')
        runtime('org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0')
        runtime('com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1')
        runtime('com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:2.2.10')
        // For references: Jackson, httpcomponents already in lib/
    }
```

Trying "grails run-app"  :

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25, org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:jar:15.0, com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1, com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.10: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25, org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:jar:15.0, com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1, com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.10: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25, org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:jar:15.0, com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1, com.github.java-json-tools:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.10: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

I use Grails 2.5.6 and Java 8

Comment: Have you tried `grails clean` and rebuild project? Are you behind a proxy? Have you tried e.g. from home or different internet provider?

Comment: Changing to Java8 did the trick

Comment: You stated in the question that you have been already using JAVA8...

Comment: Thought I was using it. System variable was not correctly setup